# Why is Google showing these Japanese characters on search results?

Tags: google-search

When I do a search for this website (very old) that I'm giving a little facelift it shows these characters which I believe are Japanese.

> [image: Japanese Characters?]

The customer was unhappy with a previous company that built them this site, and they moved it to HostGator, the site was copied using HTTrack Website copier and then it was uploaded to HostGator on the 31st of May, ever since then it's been showing these characters when you do a search for delta lock or deltalock.biz

This is very frustrating, HostGator says it has nothing to do with them and to call "the google" about the issue. I think it might have to do with the page coding, and also that the site was .asp pages but after it was copied they were copied as .html.

Answer (score 4):

Just happened to me yesterday.

I detected that someone had injected code (big security breach) in one of my web site index, and that code redirected google and yahoo to a page that was also hosted on my site that was a copy of a japanese store.

To resolve the issue with the search crawlers (google and yahoo) (the security breach is another subject) i did the following:

1. Created a new and clean index page
2. Deleted all strange templates of my site
3. Signed On Google Search Console (if you haven't done so, you will need to verify the site is yours)
4. Crawl > Fetch as Google
5. Once the page loaded correctly and the site name and description was ok i "Submitted To Index" in about a day everything was back to normal.

Malicious code
[Screenshot of index template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAaoo.png)